# How can I find which keys are absent from a Python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

`d` is a Python `dict` mapping (some of) the integers in `range(x)` to values.  How can I find which integers in that range are *not* mapped, and set them to a default value?

I do not want to just the dict's default, because I want the missing ints to appear in `d.items()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the range and `setdefault` each key:

```
for i in range(x):
    d.setdefault(i, 42)
```

Note that `setdefault` sets a default value *for that key* (not the whole dictionary), if and only if that key isn't already set to something else.

You could also use a comprehension with `get` and a default value to build a new dictionary and assign it to `d`:

```
d = {i: d.get(i, 42) for i in range(x)}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dict.keys()` works much like a set and can even be used with `range`. Applying XOR works

```
>>> d = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> d.update((k, None) for k in (d.keys() ^ range(10)))
>>> d
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 0: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, though perhaps inefficient method, might be the following where ‘x’ defines the range and ‘42’ the default value:

```
for i in range(x):
    d[i] = d.get(i, 42)
```